# Where from Silverlight knows that OOB application is already installed or not?

Tags: javascript, c#, silverlight

How Silverlight knows when to show "Install [appName] on this computer" or "Remove this Application" when rightClick on Silverlight form?

[image]

And how I can get access to this data from aspx file?

I need something like:

```
if (oob.installed)
{
//do this
}
```

Comment: I believe `Application.Current.InstallState` is what you want. But I don't know how you can get access to that from the ASPX.

Comment: Silverlight somehow gets this informaiton. But how...?